# Django API didn't detect a field in my database

Tags: python, django, web, pycharm

I'm doing the Django official tutorial, here are the models I wrote and migrated

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(name="date published")


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and I used the command `python manage.py shell` to use the Django API and ran the following commands:

```
>>> from polls.models import Question, Choice
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mohammedi/.virtualenvs/mywebsite1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Question() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pub_date'
```

what the hell is wrong with this

Comment: Did you run a makemigrations/migrate?

Comment: Are you sure there is no comma at the end of `pub_date = ...`?

Comment: I did run makemigrations/migrate and i'm sure there's no comma at the end of pub_date = ...

Comment: Can you run `print(Question.pub_date)` and include the printed value here?

Comment: here's the printed value Mr. schilling `AttributeError: type object 'Question' has no attribute 'pub_date'

Comment: That can't be. It should be something like `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute>`

Comment: Removing the argument `name="date published` and remigrating gets the job done, thank you